# C++ calling managed COM object can't find dependent assemblies

Tags: c#, c++, com

I've created and registered a managed COM library in C# on my development machine. I've successfully registered it and created a .tlb file with regasm, and successfully imported the tlb into a c++ console app used for testing.

My COM assembly is called "efcAPI.dll" and it references another assembly that has not been set up for COM or registered in anyway called "efcServerDiscovery.dll". This second dll contains some code used by my COM dll and exists in the same folder as efcAPI.dll.

Everything concerning loading the COM assembly works fine. I can create instances of my classes defined in the COM and call methods from them. However when I call certain methods that use the code defined in efcServerDiscovery.dll I get a _com_error which reports that it could not load file or assembly 'efcServerDiscovery'.

I've verified that everywhere on my hard drive where efcAPI.dll exists there's a copy of efcServerDiscovery.dll (which is just the location I built and registered efcAPI.dll from). I've also attempted to place efcAPI.dll and efcServerDiscovery.dll in the same directory as the c++ app with no success.

Any suggestions as to where the c++ app is looking for the assembly or how to discover where it's looking would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a problem with COM components having non-COM dependencies.  Windows doesn't consider the location of the COM DLL when it searches for dependent DLLs.  The normal search rules are in effect, the folder that contains the EXE first, Windows directories, current working directory, PATH environment.  The location of the COM server does not play a role.

Assuming you don't want to deploy to the EXE folder, none of these are good places to store your DLL, although plenty of installers made the desperation move of storing it in c:\windows\system32 or modify the system PATH environment variable.

One thing you could do is P/Invoke SetDllDirectory() in your C# code before running any code in the DLL.  Using Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location will do it.  That is however not a safe thing to do though, it might alter the search rules for the app that uses your component.

The only real fix is to install the DLL in the Windows side-by-side cache (WinSxS) and to include a manifest in your C# executable.  Given the state of [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374191%28VS.85%29.aspx), I can only wish you the best of luck.

Comment: Well, placing the dll in the same directory as the c++ executable will allow it to load it. While I thought I had tried this before, turns out I had mistaken which executable was being run by Visual Studio. Thanks for all the help! I'm going with this for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

In these situations i always start with [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) verifying that what & where its trying to load is what i think it is.

Comment: Hey ruddy, I tried this but depends only shows MSCOREE.DLL as a dependency for efcAPI.dll. efcServerDiscovery.dll is no where to be seen.

Comment: That probably because of the assemblies getting dynamically loaded.  You could try ProcessMonitor (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) it lets you see much of what a process is trying to do - it does a lot, but you can filter out the noise and just see what the app is trying to access file wise.

Comment: Yep, ProcessMonitor shows the app looking for the dll in the locations nobugz mentioned in his post. This helped me find the application directory it was querying. I accidentally had it in the wrong spot. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

fuslogvw will tell you where the CLR is looking for assemblies

Answer (score 0):

Or use GAC.

(here are your characters, stackoverflow)